# Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in my query. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have the following query in php/mysql:

```
$q2 = $conn3->prepare("SELECT (t.start_time + INTERVAL t.text_duration SECOND) as end_time FROM texts t WHERE t.start_time <= :starttime AND (t.start_time + INTERVAL t.text_duration SECOND) >= :starttime AND t.plot_id = :plot_id LIMIT 1"); 
$q2->bindValue(':starttime', $start_timestamp);
$q2->bindValue(':plot_id', $plot_id);
$q2->execute();
$check2 = $q2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

`$start_time` is a datetime object defined as follows:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$start_timestamp = $date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('10 minutes'));
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error:  Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in ...
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have a `DateTime` object when you called `DateTime::add()`. <s>You still have to convert it to a timestamp. Use [`DateTime::getTimestamp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) to do that.</s> You still need to convert it to a datetime value. Use [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to do this.

```
$start_timestamp = $date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('10 minutes'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for a confusion here, I want to avoid using timestamps and only use datetime objects, that's why the type here is `datetime`, only the name suggest it's a timestamp (but it's not)... How can I fix it without using timestamps then?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You need a *date*, not an object.  What data type is the column `starttime`?

Comment: The type for starttime is `datetime`. I want to avoid using timestamps and focus on datetime's - is it possible to do that like this?